# Stored Procedure Inserts date value one less than the actual date in the XML string

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am using XML to insert/update/delete records in table. But when I insert the row, the date value is inserted one less than the actual value. Below is the code for my Stored Procedure

```
IF(@Mode='UPDATE_TABLE')
BEGIN
    ;WITH XmlData AS 
        (
            SELECT
                NDS.DT.value('(ClaimExpenseID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimExpenseID',
                NDS.DT.value('(ClaimID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ClaimID',
                NDS.DT.value('(POrderID)[1]', 'int') AS 'POrderID',
                NDS.DT.value('(SiteID)[1]', 'int') AS 'SiteID',
                NDS.DT.value('(FromDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'FromDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(ToDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ToDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(ParticularID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ParticularID',
                NDS.DT.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS 'Description',
                NDS.DT.value('(SubmittedAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'SubmittedAmount',
                NDS.DT.value('(CreatedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'CreatedDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedAmount)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApprovedAmount',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApprovedDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'ApprovedDate',
                NDS.DT.value('(Remark)[1]', 'varchar(300)') AS 'Remark',
                NDS.DT.value('(ApproveBy)[1]', 'int') AS 'ApproveBy',                   
                NDS.DT.value('(RowInfo)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'RowInfo'

            FROM 
                @xmlString.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)

        )

        MERGE INTO dbo.ClaimExpenseTRS CET
        USING XmlData x ON CET.ClaimExpenseID = x.ClaimExpenseID
        WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'UPDATE'
           THEN 
             UPDATE SET 
                CET.ClaimID=x.ClaimID,  
                CET.CreatedDate=x.CreatedDate,
                CET.POrderID=x.POrderID,
                CET.SiteID=x.SiteID,
                CET.FromDate=x.FromDate,
                CET.ToDate=x.ToDate,
                CET.ParticularID=x.ParticularID,
                CET.Description=x.Description,
                CET.SubmittedAmount=x.SubmittedAmount,
                CET.ApprovedAmount=x.ApprovedAmount,
                CET.Remarks=x.Remark,
                CET.ApproveBy=x.ApproveBy,
                CET.ApprovedDate=x.ApprovedDate

      WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'DELETE'AND CET.ClaimExpenseID = x.ClaimExpenseID
           THEN DELETE 

        WHEN NOT MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'NEW'
           THEN 
              INSERT(ClaimID, CreatedDate, POrderID, SiteID,FromDate,ToDate,ParticularID,                 Description,SubmittedAmount,ApprovedAmount,Remarks,ApproveBy,ApprovedDate)
              VALUES(x.ClaimID,x.CreatedDate,x.POrderID,x.SiteID,x.FromDate,x.ToDate,x. 
              ParticularID,x.Description,x.SubmittedAmount,x.ApprovedAmount,x.Remark,x.                   ApproveBy,x.ApprovedDate);
END
```

This is the XML string..

```
<NewDataSet>
  <DataTable>
     <ClaimExpenseID>5</ClaimExpenseID>
     <ClaimID>1</ClaimID>
     <CreatedDate>2011-08-01T00:00:00+05:30</CreatedDate>
     <POrderID>11</POrderID>
     <SiteID>4</SiteID>
     <FromDate>2011-08-07T00:00:00+05:30</FromDate>
     <ToDate>2011-08-08T00:00:00+05:30</ToDate>
     <NoOfDays>1</NoOfDays>
     <ParticularID>1</ParticularID>
     <Description>test</Description>
     <SubmittedAmount>500</SubmittedAmount>
     <Month>August</Month>
     <Year>2011</Year>
     <POrderNo>PO0002</POrderNo>
     <SiteName>SITE 2</SiteName>
     <ParticulerName>Food</ParticulerName>
     <RowInfo>UNCHANGED</RowInfo>
     <TableRowIndex>3</TableRowIndex>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
    <ClaimID>1</ClaimID>
    <CreatedDate>2011-09-22T00:00:00+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <POrderID>26</POrderID>
    <SiteID>1</SiteID>
    <FromDate>2011-09-22T00:00:00+05:30</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2011-09-30T00:00:00+05:30</ToDate>
    <NoOfDays>8</NoOfDays>
    <ParticularID>1</ParticularID>
    <Description>dinner</Description>
    <SubmittedAmount>200</SubmittedAmount>
    <POrderNo>PO-01</POrderNo>
    <SiteName>ALKAPURI</SiteName>
    <ParticulerName>Food</ParticulerName>
    <RowInfo>NEW</RowInfo>
    <TableRowIndex>4</TableRowIndex>
   </DataTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

In second data table the from date value is 2011-09-22 and To date value is 2011-09-30 but when the value inserted in the database table it becomes 2011-09-21 and 2011-09-29 respectively..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be your +5:30 timezone? Is this the same as your database or is your database trying to work out the time in a different timezone and coming up with the previous day?

Edit: I just confirmed this. If I read your date time: `2011-09-30T00:00:00+05:30` into my machine (based in the UK), I get a return of `2011-09-29 18:30:00.000`

The code I used for the conversion was :

`select cast('' as xml).value('xs:dateTime("2011-09-30T00:00:00+05:30")', 'datetime')`

Comment: @JHolyhead..When I write Select GETDATE(), it shows me the actual date and time....I am in India and Indian time zone is +5:30

Comment: run the query above in your management studio and tell me what it returns.

Comment: select cast('' as xml).value('xs:dateTime("2011-09-30T00:00:00+05:30")', 'datetime') returns 2011-09-29 18:30:00.000 and at the same time select GETDATE() returns 2011-09-22 16:33:35.210

Comment: It's probably the locale set on your server. It can be telling the correct time and still have the wrong timezone set. I think MSSQL gets that info from the server BIOS.

Comment: @JHolyhead..So what to do in that case. Still not getting your point. How to know which time zone the server is running???

Comment: Check Control Panel > Date and Time (Timezone Tab). You could probably just remove the offset from the datetime, but that depends on if you can control the contents of the xml. Looks like your server is running UTC+0.